# Entity Framework Add-Migration throwing an exception, but is successful

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server application that uses Entity Framework. When I run Add-Migration, it is successful, but throws the following exception when done:

```
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"LouisHowe.web.Program","Message":"Application starting up","State":{"Message":"Application starting up","{OriginalFormat}":"Application starting up"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Critical","Category":"LouisHowe.web.Program","Message":"Unhandled exception in Main()","Exception":"Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostAbortedException: The host was aborted.
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.ThrowHostAborted()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostFactoryResolver.HostingListener.OnNext(KeyValuePair\u00602 value)
at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.ResolveHost(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DiagnosticListener diagnosticListener)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
at LouisHowe.web.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\git\\LouisHowe\\LouisHowe.web\\Program.cs:line 211","State":{"Message":"Unhandled exception in Main()","{OriginalFormat}":"Unhandled exception in Main()"}}
```

Line 211 is:

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

It's not a big problem as the migration is successful. But it's annoying.

Also, when I run the app, that line executes fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of .NET and EF Core tools are you using

Comment: @mpoust 7.0.10 - and I'll upgrade to 7.0.11 shortly